# Генерация Dockerfile для уже существующего контейнера

Tags: docker

У меня есть docker контейнер, как по нему написать docker файл?

Comment: По имеющемуся контейнеру ни как. Надо писать файл по мере заполнения контейнера, точно зная какое ПО и для чего вы в него добавляете

Comment: Если у вас есть контейнер, то есть и image, возможно вам подойдет, что-то такое https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104847/how-to-generate-a-dockerfile-from-an-image, но полностью правильный Dockerfile оно не создаст,  но достаточно близкий к нему

Comment: Посмотреть историю `docker history --no-trunc` и написать «по мотивам»